# How long batteries last with 5DMIII off?

Tags: canon, battery, canon-5d-mark-iii, battery-grip

I have a 5DMIII with genuine Canon batteries and genuine battery grip. With the camera turned off, I found that two batteries (in the grip) last for about 10 days, maybe more but I never tested.

Did you find the same results? To me it doesn't look like a long time.

Comment: Should last a hell of a lot longer than that!  I have the 5DMIII with genuine batteries and genuine grip, and I can leave it weeks and when I turn it on they are exactly the same as they were (not that I've really checked properly)...

Comment: If you had GPS built in the story would be different. If I leave the built-in GPS on with my Canon 6D in standby mode, the battery drains in about a week. Without the GPS on it will last months without an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have let my 5D Mark iii go for months without charging batteries without problem, even taking it out and using it occasionally.  I have all official Canon gear and I think the longest period yet without charging is probably about 5 months and that was due to use, not loss of charge.  If you are losing power in 10 days, you have a short or a defective battery.  I would suggest contacting a Canon Service Center for assistance.

Out of camera, I've had a set of LP-E6s sit outside the camera for about 8 months and retain over 90% power. If forget the exact level they were at, but I'm pretty sure it was upwards of 95%. To the best of my knowledge, the off switch means the camera actually turns off completely, so battery life in camera when turned off should be similar and thus is likely measured in years.

Update:
One other thought to check, do you have the switch on or off for the controls on the battery grip?  I don't believe this matters, but it might be something worth checking.  I'm pretty sure they pull power from the camera, but if they pull direct from the batteries, then a button from the controls being pushed while they are switched on could cause a drain.

Comment: I would have said months in my comment too except that I've never left it that long without using it -- lol! :)

Comment: @Mike, I haven't left it that long without using it either, but I've had it take months to use go through the batteries from use, and given that the number of shots I took in that time roughly correspond to how many shots I'd get on the set of batteries to start with, I'd say it is really darn near indefinitely.  Off seems to be genuinely off unless you leave the switch on and let it go in to the auto-power down mode.

Comment: agreed.  The LP-E6's last forever and having two of them in a grip like that should definitely last darn near indefinitely as you say.

Comment: I am beginning to think that the batteries might be defective. Canon Service Center did not find anything. They think it's LCD auto-off function disabled. Aren't these supposed to be genuine http://goo.gl/JYCA7r? These are the ones I have...

Comment: @Bob - yeah, those are certainly first party and genuine if they are coming from Amazon directly.  You aren't the only person to talk about having this problem.  We had someone else with a similar problem a while back and not sure what happened with it, but it very much sounds like some kind of defect in either the camera, the grip or the batteries themselves.  The best way to isolate is to try seeing if the batteries lose power while outside of the camera entirely.

Comment: You can also see if the batteries still drain directly in the camera, though that doesn't necessarily rule out the camera body since I believe the grip interfaces the power differently.  Good luck, I certainly know I'd be frustrated if I was in your shoes.